# Magento - Sidebar Category Filter, URLs not start from root

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a single root category containing a single sub-category in my shop. It is set as an anchor to enable to dynamic attribute filters in my left hand column for navigation.

Whilst the filters render fine, and work flawlessly from the home page, when I navigate to a CMS page (or any page OTHER then the home page) the URLs are incorrect, e.g.

from home page:

http://www.domain.com/category_name.html?price=10-20

from the Contact Us page:

http://www.domain.com/contacts/category_name.html?price=10-20

As you see, its using the CMS page URL as the base path.

There are no settings for the filter URLs.

I am using the following code to display the filter sidebar navigation:

```
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="product-range">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Browse Products') ?></h2>
    <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
    <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
            <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
            <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
            <nav>
                <dl>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__('Browse by '.$_filter->getName()); ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <?php echo str_replace(array('?','/?'), array('tapes.html?','/tapes.html?'), $_filter->getHtml()) ?>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </nav>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

"tapes.html" is the category URL (i only have the one category, this works fine!)

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use slash for both replacements like this:

```
<?php 

echo str_replace(array('?','/?'), 
                 array('/tapes.html?','/tapes.html?'), 
                 $_filter->getHtml()) 

?>
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure that would make much difference. Will try it all the same and report back! (I had minor success using "../tapes.html?" but it failed in some instances.

Comment: No dice. On a CMS page, e.g. Product Advice, the filter links turn out as "http://www.domain.com/product-advice/tapes.html?price=10-20"